# How to highlight a selection in a view in Android with Java

Tags: java, android, android-framelayout

So what I am trying to achieve is the following.

If a user click on one of the two images in a Framelayout, the image get highlighted (denotes that it was selected).

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/field_background" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/forty" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/hundred" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Would I need to add an other ImageView under the two `ImageView`s (`@drawable/forty` and `@drawable/hundred`) and then in the associated `Activity` reference those images and highlight them? or is it all done in the `Activity` view where I can add the highlight image directly there?

Im new to Android so I am having issues understanding the best path forward.

### UPDATE:

Included the desired effect.
[image]

Comment: onclick -> background yellow?

Comment: Really!? So I can put in a onclicklistner and just do the background yellow in Android!? Imma try it, thx for the insight, with xCode you have to stack the view with ZStack which is why I was asking if the same is required in Android.

Comment: Yes. The View parameter to the onClick method is the clicked view. All views have a background/color attribute that can be set

Comment: So I implemented your suggestion but its not visually appealing, it just sets the entire background to the color!? I was hoping to get line an outlined glow of the image? I have added the rest in the question for reference.